# How to clone a theme template from within Wordpress?

Tags: themes, templates

I'm looking at the Raft theme and its got 8 templates, including one called Front Page.

I wanted to clone Front Page to 'Front Page Modified' so I could have on it and still keep the original in its original form.

I was able to add a new template using the Add New > Custom Template UI, but I don't see a way to copy the original Front Page contents template over to my new copy.

I *do* see a 'Copy all blocks' in the editor menu, but when I try to paste, nothing happens.

Thanks.

...Wordpress version 6.1.1.

Comment: Easiest option would probably be to edit the front page template, open the three dots menu, select Code Editor, copy all the code, and then when adding a new template switch to the code editor and paste everything you copied.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. Your solution _seemed_ to work perfectly -- copy, paste, done. Great. But, when I went to actually use it, all the wrong things started happening. This could be 100% oeprator error, but I want to try to figure it out first, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "oeprator error"?

Comment: @Cyclonecode operator error = user error, i.e. it might another mistake Peter's made.